# Removing new lines containing spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file test.txt:

```
this is test line
  another line
2146554
 145648
    DATE 2017-12-12

USR-PASSWORD *\#5%*sdfdaw*eewaqd*

 TYPE ---NULLS--- TBL
PWD-TOD 2018-01-01
 EDBS
  18/01/02 KEYFROM 


 SDBS
```

Where you see empty lines they actually contain 3 spaces. I am already able to remove any line containing specific words:

```
<?php
$file = file('test.txt'); 
$key = '17.2';
$cleaned = array();

//CLEANUP START
$unwanted_words = array(" DATE", "USR-PASSWORD", "PWD-TOD", "KEYFROM ");
$unwanted_words_match = '(?:' . join('|', array_map(function($word) {
    return preg_quote($word, '/');
}, $unwanted_words)) . ')';

$replace_match = '/^.*' . $unwanted_words_match . '.*$[\r\n]/m';
$result = preg_replace($replace_match, '', $file);

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
  if(!empty($value)) {
    $cleaned[] = $value;
    echo  $value . "<br />";
  }
}

?>
```

The last step is to remove those lines with 3 spaces. I tried

```
\n[ ]{3,}
```

but my reg ex knowledge ends there.

Text file: https://jsfiddle.net/adsj0rw9/1/

Comment: I'd suggest you make a live demo as we don't see input string as is.

Comment: Try `$file = preg_replace('~^ {3}$\R*~m', '', $file)`

Comment: If you mean any horizontal whitespace, try `preg_replace('~^\h{3}$\R*~um', '', $file)`, change `{3}` to `{3,`} if there can be more than 3.

Comment: I'd also suggest replacing `'.*$[\r\n]/m'` with `'.*$\R?/m'`

Comment: Does either of that work for you?

Comment: Can you specify what $file does? Is it replacing the original test.txt file with preg_replace pattern? Unfortunately neither the php output neither the text file is updated... Getting the same result as it was without it.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/5GbLPo

Comment: Updated with fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adsj0rw9/1/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as I see the output, it still shows empty lines. My end goal is to see line 145648 and then immediately the next line: TYPE ---....

Comment: @gVoid There are  blank lines with fewer whitespace than 3 - your input contains such lines. BTW, why JSFiddle? Are you working in JS? [**Here is a demo with more than 3 spaces in each blank line**](https://ideone.com/UEnQLf)

Comment: Okay one question to shed some light on it, all lines beginning with three space characters or blank lines beginning as such?

Comment: @revo Thank you for your suggestion but it is basically the same as \n[ ]{3,} which matches lines which also exceeds 3 spaces (if I try a string with 4 spaces and text it also matches that).
I would like to match new line and 3 spaces only (no words or any characters after 3 spaces. Example:
 //this is new line
   //3 spaces end the line

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now it looks almost OK - when I try exact same code it outputs in a single line. Also I would like to read it from a file since it can be 20 000+ lines to cleanup...
No I don't use JS just used random site to display text file.

Comment: So you shouldn't use comma `,` in quantifying: `{3}` and add `$` to assert end of line: `(?m)^[ ]{3}$` (this removes spaces but not line) to remove line as well you should do this: `(?m)^[ ]{3}$\R?`. Here is a live demo https://regex101.com/r/BSQMKj/1

Comment: @revo Finally! When I try it in my text editor (sublime text) it finally selects what I need. Tons of thanks!!! Now I have to implement this into php script without messing existing pattern.

Comment: @revo Can you post it as an answer so other people can also find it without having to go through all these comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `{Min,}` in regex means match ***at least*** `Min` time(s). To match exactly three space characters, you have to remove comma `,` in brace notation quantifier: `^[ ]{3}`. Then you should look for any following newline character to take it off:

```
(?m)^   $\R?
```