# Regular expression does not work with PHP

Tags: php, regex

This is a continuation to the previous case: [Removing new lines containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882786/removing-new-lines-containing-spaces)

Now I have a working regular expression:

```
R^[ ]{3}$
```

which finds new line and 3 spaces after it.

In PHP I use:

```
$result = preg_replace('/R^[ ]{3}$/', '', $file);
```

Which should remove such occurrences. However the output remains unchanged. Consider the following example:

```
UID(*****************ABCDXXX) ALLOW

UID(*****************EFGHXSX) ALLOW
```

There are 3 spaces in line 2. End result should be:

```
UID(*****************ABCDXXX) ALLOW
UID(*****************EFGHXSX) ALLOW
```

Since I get input from a file, here is how I output the result:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
        echo  $value . "<br />";
    }
}
```

I also tried this regular expression but, as you might gathered, it did not work:

```
\n.{3}$
```

Comment: You need [`'/\R {3}$/m'`](https://ideone.com/sUhmeL), note the ``\\`` before `R` and the `m` modifier

Comment: Hello Wiktor. I already tried this - but it still refuses to delete that line = no changes.

Comment: See [`preg_replace('/\R {3}$/m', '<br/>', $s)`](https://ideone.com/sUhmeL). If you want to match any horizontal whitespace, and you work with Unicode, use `preg_replace('/\R\h{3}$/mu', '<br/>', $s)`

Comment: I looked at your example at https://ideone.com/sUhmeL and it works if I copy paste to my server. But it still does not work with file input.

Comment: Then what you posted here is not exactly what you have in the file, or you have some encoding issues (and the problem is caused elsewhere).

Comment: I tried using ANSI and UTF-8. But thank you for taking a look anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new line depends on the platform you run your code in, so on the contents of the file. In Windows this is `\r\n`, in *Nix `\n` so we should make `\r` optional.

```
$result = preg_replace('/\r?\n[\ ]{3}/', '<br />', $file);
```

Comment: I run it on Windows. Again, text editor (Sublime Text) accepts this regular expression, but my output is unchanged. I start to wonder it is not the code at fault...

Comment: The file may contain `\n` new lines anyway if it was saved so. Anyway take a look at the [proof-of-concept](https://3v4l.org/4CouC).

Answer (score -4):

Try with this:

```
$pattern = "/(<(?!\/)[^>]+>)+(<\/[^>]+>)+/";
$html = preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ')'